# error rhc app delete 500 error code

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to delete an app and getting a 500 error code.  The app is temp-cartracker.rhcloud.com (I also have temp2-cartracker.rhcloud.com that I can't delete, either)

```
$ rhc app delete temp -d
DEBUG: Using config file /Users/smenzer/.openshift/express.conf
DEBUG: Git config 'git config --get rhc.app-id' returned ''
DEBUG: Git config 'git config --get rhc.app-name' returned ''
DEBUG: Git config 'git config --get rhc.domain-name' returned ''
DEBUG: Authenticating with RHC::Auth::Token
DEBUG: Connecting to https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Getting all domains
DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6
DEBUG: Using token authentication
DEBUG: Created new httpclient
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG:    code 200  530 ms
DEBUG: Server supports API versions 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6
DEBUG:    Using API version 1.6
DEBUG: Client API version 1.6 is not current. Refetching API
DEBUG: Using token authentication
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG:    code 200  159 ms
DEBUG: Using token authentication
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains
DEBUG:    code 200  141 ms
DEBUG: Using token authentication
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/domains/cartracker/applications/temp
DEBUG:    code 200  195 ms
This is a non-reversible action! Your application code and data will be permanently deleted if you continue!

Are you sure you want to delete the application 'temp'? (yes|no): yes

Deleting application 'temp' ... DEBUG: Deleting application temp
DEBUG: Using token authentication
DEBUG: Request DELETE https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/application/53617aae500446ad820001b5
DEBUG:    code 501   99 ms
DEBUG: Response did not include a message from server: invalid character at "<HTML><HEA"
Server returned an unexpected error code: 501
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a temporary issue with OpenShift service. Can you try deleting the app from OpenShift web console? You can delete apps via web console as well https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications